# Datatype supported in Oracle but not in Excel

Tags: sql, oracle, excel, vba

I am writing a macro which pulls data from Oracle and displays in Excel.  In Oracle DB we have a custom table with a column Named "Calculated_Quantity".  The datatype of this column is BINARY_DOUBLE.

When I query for this column in Oracle using SQL developer I am able to view the data.  However when I write the same query in Excel macro, I get the error as "Data Type is not Supported".

Any suggestions what do I need to do here.  If needed I can post my query here.

Thanks,

Comment: `CAST` or `CONVERT` it into a supported type in your `SELECT`.

Comment: How do I do that...
I am writing a simple SQL statement as:- 
SELECT CALCULATED_QUANTITY FROM DW_STG_FSN.SAMPLE

Comment: Ok.. I managed to get it through CAST.  However now when I am trying to sum it errors out.  Seems to be a syntax error. 

If I write the statement as "Select Id, SUM(CAST(A.CALCULATED_QUANTITY AS NUMBER(10))) ONHANDSAMPLEQUANTITY from DW.SAMPLE", it works fine. but the calculation is wrong.

If I write "Select Id, CAST(SUM(A.CALCULATED_QUANTITY AS NUMBER(10))) ONHANDSAMPLEQUANTITY from DW.SAMPLE", I get an error as missing right parenthesis.  The parenthesis seem to be correct.  

Help please!

Comment: Sorry, but that's a totally different question, and posting it in a comment here is unclear (and not useful to future readers here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `CAST` (or `CONVERT` for some DBMSs) to convert the data to a supported datatype.

```
SELECT 
  CAST(CALCULATED_QUANTITY AS NUMBER(10)) AS Qty 
FROM 
  DW_STG_FSN.SAMPLE
```